# MyBatis custom queries: why not generate model and mapper methods?

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

Why does the MyBatis Java generator not create:

1. a Java model for custom result maps; and
2. Java mapper methods for custom queries?

Custom queries and result maps are based on MyBatis SqlMap XML, and thus I would think that it should be possible to create the model class and add the methods to the Mapper class.

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but reading the [Introduction to MyBatis Generator](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/), I understand it generates Java POJOs and CRUD SQL statements XML + matching Java Mappers.

No result maps since generated POJOs properties name matches table columns names: no need because this mapping is implicitly handled.

MyBatis Generator generates stuff from DB, not from sqlMap XML.

Comment: It does this only for DB tables introspected. It generates the XML for these tables, the model Java class(es) (POJO) for the result map(s), and the Mapper Java interface with the standard methods. MyBatis does not seem to process the custom XML to do the same. At least I have not found any way to do that.